# Signature does not Match S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am getting below error -

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details.'

The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I have checked my secret key there are no spaces in it.

My key looks like -

```
TestArea/Destination/SUP000011/ATM-1B4L2KQ0ZE0-0001/SoS_Update_2018_06_04_pram.pptx
```

Code -

```
 public static Stream GetObjectStream(string keyName)
        {
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = keyName
            };

                using (AmazonS3Client StorageClient = GetClient())
//This line gives error (getting response)
                using (GetObjectResponse response = StorageClient.GetObject(request))
            using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
            {
                return responseStream;
            }
        }

public static Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client GetClient()
        {
            AmazonS3Config Config = new AmazonS3Config();
            AmazonS3Client StorageClient;

            Config.RegionEndpoint = null;
            Config.ServiceURL = ConfigurationManager.NGDMSobjECSEndPoint;
            Config.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            Config.ForcePathStyle = true;

            StorageClient = new AmazonS3Client(ConfigurationManager.NGDMSobjECSUser, ConfigurationManager.NGDMSobjECSKey, Config);

            return StorageClient;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was problem with my Secret Key, i created new Secret Key and it worked.